# Why isn't my form working with my modules?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have an `auth` module, and would like to keep a `Login` form in the `forms` folder in the module. I have my class named `Auth_Form_Login` and the code I use to instantiate it in `auth`'s `Index` controller is:

```
$loginForm = new Auth_Form_Login($_POST);
```

However, Zend is complaining that it can't find the class. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

My directory structure is like so:

```
application
    configs
    layouts
    modules
        auth
            controllers
            models
            views
                forms      <--- This is what I want to autoload from
        default
            controllers
            models
            views

library
public
```

Also, modules are set up correctly:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = false
```

Comment: Do you have your `Admin` module bootstrap in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're missing module bootstrap for `Auth` module:

```
application
     modules
         auth
             Bootstrap.php
```

Which might consist of this only line - just to make autoloading magic work:

```
class Auth_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {}
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense. But, it's still not working. My application has a namespace, "SomeName", that I use for Controller plugins (e.g. `SomeName_Controller_Plugin_Test`). Do I need the `SomeName` namespace anywhere in the Auth module? For example, do I need `SomeName_Auth_Form_Login` or anything like that?

Comment: I think what I just mentioned is the problem, because I'm getting errors like this: `Application error caught in ErrorController: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'include_once(SomeName\Auth\Form\Login.php`. It seems like either the base path isn't set up correctly or there are more namespacing problems

Comment: No, you don't need that. Another thing to check is if you initialized modules in your `application.ini` like this: `resources.modules[] =`

Comment: Just put that in, but same error message. Will ZF know that I have bootstrap files in my module directories?

Comment: Ok, never mind that question, I can confirm that Zend is using the Auth Bootstrap file.

Comment: Did you rename it to `SomeName_Auth_Form_Login`? It should be named `Auth_Form_Login` and called from your `index` controller with this name.

Comment: @Vika: YES! Thank you! It works now! :) When the removed the `SomeName` namespace from the class name it works! Thank you again!

Comment: You know, I love Zend Framework, but the directory structure and autoloading is less than obvious. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You're doing everything right in your form initialisation. The autoloader simply doesn't know where to find it so you need to setup zend autoloader correctly.

I am not sure how you created your module based structure. I use the [**cli tool**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html) which configures everything.

So in my application.ini file I have:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules = ''
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"
```

And in my Boostrap.php:

```
$modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader ( 
                      array ('namespace' => '', 'basePath' 
                                         => APPLICATION_PATH . 
                                             '/modules/default' ) );
```

You also can setup the [**autoloader manually by registering your resources**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html):

```
$resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
    'basePath' => 'path/to/my/directory',
    'namespace' => 'Auth',
    'resourceType' => array(
       'form' => array(
            'path' => 'forms/'
            'namespace' => 'Form'
        )
        //...your code
     )
   )
);
```

Comment: What should my basePath be? I've added my directory structure to my question.

Comment: you have a wrong project structure, the form folder has to be placed in the auth directory and not in the views directory of auth

Comment: Ok, I've moved it, but it's still giving me this error: `Application error caught in ErrorController: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'include_once(SomeName\Auth\Form\Login.php)...`

Comment: Your form is Auth_Form_Login and not SomeName_... so remove that